# Python/Pygame errors in class inheritance

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, inheritance, pygame

So I've been working with classes and inheritance and from my limited understanding, I've gathered that attributes should be inherited. However, the first set of code below throws this error: 'AttributeError: type object 'Characters' has no attribute 'posX' with the below code:

```
class Characters(object):
def __init__(self,health,posX,posY,width,height,dead,moveSpeed,yMove,xMove):
    self.health = health
    self.posX = posX
    self.posY = posY
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.dead = dead
    #self.image = image
    self.yMove = yMove
    self.xMove = xMove


class Player(Characters):
def __init__(self,images,gameOver):
    self.images = (config.get('player'))
    self.gameOver = gameOver


def move(self):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.gameOver = True

    keysPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keysPressed[pygame.K_w]:
        Characters.yMove = -Characters.moveSpeed
        Characters.image = self.images[1]
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_s]:
        Characters.yMove = Characters.moveSpeed
        Characters.image = self.images[0]
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_a]:
        Characters.xMove = -Characters.moveSpeed
        Characters.image = self.images[2]
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_d]:
        Characters.xMove = Characters.moveSpeed
        Characters.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.images[2],True,False)

    Characters.posX += Characters.xMove
    Characters.posY += Characters.yMove
```

And with the below code, it throws the error: AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'posX'

```
class Player(Characters):
def __init__(self,images,gameOver,posX,posY):
    self.images = (config.get('player'))
    self.gameOver = gameOver
    self.posX = posX
    self.posY = posY

def move(self):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.gameOver = True

    keysPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keysPressed[pygame.K_w]:
        Characters.yMove = -Characters.moveSpeed
        Characters.image = self.images[1]
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_s]:
        Characters.yMove = Characters.moveSpeed
        Characters.image = self.images[0]
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_a]:
        Characters.xMove = -Characters.moveSpeed
        Characters.image = self.images[2]
    if keysPressed[pygame.K_d]:
        Characters.xMove = Characters.moveSpeed
        Characters.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.images[2],True,False)

    self.posX += Characters.xMove
    self.posY += Characters.yMove
```

I have tried using `*args` and `**kwargs`, the `super` method, and `Parent.__init__(self, attr1, attr2,...)`, but it still throws the same errors. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The instance variables are inherited so they're accessible simply by referencing them through `self`, don't use `Characters`. As a basic example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 3;

class B(A):
    def thefoo(self):
        print self.foo

b = B()
b.thefoo()
```

Here, B inherits the instance variable foo from A and as you can see, self.foo in an instance of B returns the inherited value.

Comment: See, that's what I thought initially, but it's still throwing this error: `AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'posX'`

Comment: There's no reference to pygame.Surface in your code so that error is occurring somewhere else. You should look at the line numbers and also check whether you understand the inheritance syntax in the example above.